# Order of the categorical variables in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image: Input DataFrame]

where, `a, b, c, d` are the categorical variables such that the `a < b < c < d` and `b > 3 * a`, `c > 2 * b` and `d > 1.5 * c`. If these explicit relationships  are given, how do I add rows to this dataframe with all other implicit relationships such as `c > 6 * a`, `d > 9 * a`, and `d > 3 * b`.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is a graph problem. Probably `networkx` would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a dataframe like below (I added column names for readability)

```
df
  Cat1 Cat2  Relationship
0    a    b           3.0
1    b    c           2.0
2    c    d           1.5
```

First merge `df` itself on first 2 columns and calculate the new relationship value by multiplying the original 2 relationship values on the merged row. Repeat the same until all relationships have reached.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a', 'b', 3],
                        ['b', 'c', 2],
                        ['c', 'd', 1.5]],
                  columns=['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Relationship'])
max_length_of_relationships = len(df)
for i in range(max_length_of_relationships):
    df2 = df.merge(df, left_on='Cat2', right_on='Cat1')
    df2['Relationship'] = df2['Relationship_x'] * df2['Relationship_y']
    df2 = df2[['Cat1_x', 'Cat2_y', 'Relationship']]
    df2.columns = ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Relationship']
    df = df.append(df2).drop_duplicates()
```

which yield

```
df
  Cat1 Cat2  Relationship
0    a    b           3.0
1    b    c           2.0
2    c    d           1.5
0    a    c           6.0
1    b    d           3.0
1    a    d           9.0
```

The tricky point here is I assumed the `max_length_of_relationships` is the row count of the dataframe, which is actually the worst case scenario. If you have a large dataframe while the max_length_of_relationships is small, the performance would be bad. In this case, you may need to use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) as suggested by @Quang to find the longest path in a graph.

Code Example

```py
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Cat1', 'Cat2', edge_attr=True, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
print(nx.dag_longest_path(G))
max_length_of_relationships = nx.dag_longest_path_length(G)
```

Comment: In the code that does not use `networkx`, why is the `for` statement used, especially since `i` is not used anywhere in the following statements that creates `df2`?

Comment: We need a for loop here to make sure the df join itself for n times. If you don't have a for loop and join it only once, you can only deduce 1 level of relationship, like  a<>c and b<>d, but missing a<>d.

Comment: I am revisiting this problem that I originally posted and I am encountering an additional case, where, `b < 5 * a`.  This leads to the `NetworkXUnfeasible: Graph contains a cycle or graph changed during iteration` error message. Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

as commented, this is a graph problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
 '1': {0: 'b', 1: 'c', 2: 'd'},
 '2': {0: 3.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 1.5}})

# as we multiplying, we convert the values to log
df[2] = np.log(df[2].astype(float)).astype(float)

# create the graphs
G = nx.DiGraph()

# add the edges
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(x,y,w) for 
                               x,y,w in zip(df[0],df[1],df[2])])

# compute all the path:
np.exp(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(y, index=[x]) for x,y in
            nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G)],
          sort=False)
         .replace(0, np.nan)
         .stack()

      )
```

Output:

```
a  b    3.0
   c    6.0
   d    9.0
b  c    2.0
   d    3.0
c  d    1.5
dtype: float64
```